# How to calculate the angles and hypotenuse for a triangle with sides of non-0 width.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

See the image below:

When I lay this out in Fusion, I can get the angles but I can't figure out how to calculate it mathematically.

The goal is to have the angled stretcher fully contact the upper $45$"-long support and the floor(even though there will be excess to remove.)

I'm looking for a formula for calculating the stretcher angle($35.8$ in this case) and the length that the $2\times4$ would have to be.

I already know how to calculate the angles of a right triangle, but no combination of opposite or adjacent that I can think of work.

[image: Work Table]

Comment: what is 2x4? if it is the hypotenuse (h) and angle is $\alpha$, then $h cos(\alpha)=45"$.

Comment: 2x4 is a piece of wood that's 3.5 inches wide.  What you provided isn't even a complete formula for finding the angle.

Comment: I would like to know whether you know how to calculate angles using trigonometry. The equation I have uses $\tan$. Please reply.

Comment: I know how to use SOHCAHTOA.  The question is how to know the dimensions of the triangle to use.

Comment: Sorry for the delay to reply. I had to learn SOHCAHTOA to make sure that you are capable of using the formula I would be posting. If you can calculate the square root of a given number, I think I can change the formula I have to represent the two sides of a right angle triangle, so that you can use your SOHCAHTOA to find the required angle. But, you have to give me  three or four hours to get that ready. Please be patient.

Answer (score 0):

[image: AngledStretcher]

We have changed all numerical values in your sketch to variables ($\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$). We also added three new dimensions (measures of lengths) $d$, $k$, and $x$.

$\mathrm{\underline{Theory\space} -\space for\space egg\space heads}$

$$x=\frac{2c}{\cos\left(\omega\right)}$$
$$k=h-x=h-\frac{2c}{\cos\left(\omega\right)}$$
$$d=a-2b$$

$$\tan\left(\omega\right)=\frac{k}{d}= \frac{h-\frac{2c}{\cos\left(\omega\right)}}{a-2b}$$

As shown below, we can simplify this relationship between various lengths and the angle we are looking for to get a quadratic equation in $\sin\left(\omega\right)$.
$$\left(a-2b\right)\sin\left(\omega\right)-h\cos\left(\omega\right)+2c=0$$
$$\left(h^2+\left(a-2b\right)^2\right) \sin^2\left(\omega\right)+4c\left(a-2b\right)\sin\left(\omega\right)-\left(h^2-4c^2\right)=0$$

This equation has only one positive root, and that is,
$$\sin\left(\omega\right)=\frac{h\sqrt{h^2+\left(a-2b\right)^2-4c^2}-2c\left(a-2b\right)}{h^2+\left(a-2b\right)^2},$$
from which we can easily deduce the value of $\omega$.

In order to calculate the length $L$ of the 2x4 angled wooden plank, we can use the following equation.
$$L=\frac{d}{\cos\left(\omega\right)}-2c\tan\left(\omega\right)+\frac{2x}{\sin\left(\omega\right)}$$

When we substitute values of $d$ and $x$ obtained above, we have
$$L=\frac{1 }{\cos\left(\omega\right)}\left[a-2b+2c\left(\frac{2}{\sin\left(\omega\right)}-\sin\left(\omega\right)\right)\right].$$

$\mathrm{\underline{Method\space of\space Calculation}\space -\space for\space anybody}$

First, calculate the hypotenuse $AB$ of the right angle triangle $ABC$ shown in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 2}$ using the following equation.
$$AB= h^2+\left(a-2b\right)^2$$

Then, calculate the side $BC$ using the following equation.
$$BC= h\sqrt{AB-4c^2}-2c\left(a-2b\right)$$

Now, since you have two sides of a right angle triangle, you can apply your expertise in  SOHCAHTOA to find the $\measuredangle CAB$

To determine the length $L$ of the angled plank, we need to calculate $\cos\left(\omega\right)$. First, we must find the length $CA$ though as shown below.
$$CA=\sqrt{AB^2-BC^2}$$

$\cos\left(\omega\right)$can be calculated using the following equation.
$$\cos\left(\omega\right)=\frac{CA}{AB}$$

Now, $L$ is given by
$$L=\frac{1 }{\cos\left(\omega\right)}\left[a-2b+2c\left(\frac{2}{\sin\left(\omega\right)}-\sin\left(\omega\right)\right)\right].$$

$\mathrm{\underline{An\space Example}\space -\space for\space the\space interested\space party}$

Given:  $a=45$, $b=3.5$, $c=1.75$, and $h=31.75\qquad$ Find $\omega$ and $L$.
$$AB=2452.0625, \qquad BC=1435.27404$$
$$\sin\left(CAB\right)=\frac{BC}{AB}=\frac{1435.27404}{2452.0625}=0.585333463705885$$
$$\measuredangle CAB=35.82656^o$$

$$CA=\sqrt{AB^2-BC^2}=\sqrt{2452.0625^2-1435.27404^2}=1988.114416$$
$$\cos\left(\omega\right)=\frac{1988.114416}{2452.0625}=0.810793$$
$$L=\frac{1}{0.810793}\left[45-2\times 3.5+2\times 1.75\left(\frac{2}{0.5853334}-0.5853334\right)\right]=59.0907.$$

The values of $\omega$ and $L$ were confirmed by the diagram ($\mathrm{Fig.\space 3}$), which we drew to scale in GeoGebra. The measurements shown in the diagram were obtained using integrated measuring tools available in GeoGebra.

[image: Confirnation]